# How do I remove duplicates from a drop-down list?

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, dropdown

I have a field in a list with the type drop down. It is supposed to show available countries which works. However, there are a lot of annoying duplicates of the same country. How do I remove them?

Comment: cant you remove them from the source?

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue. The field does a look up on another list with several items of same country. I cannot remove these items since they have other fields containing unique values.

Comment: isn't "Enforce unique values" an option? I mean, you can always try to do it on the DOM, but I guess the best way would be to fix root of the problem

Comment: I am afraid that there is nothing to fix since the list is intentionally made so that several items with the same country can be added. I was just telling you the reason why I cannot delete those items since they have other fields with text that is unique. The field "country" in that list (and by that list I mean the source)  is just used to group them.

Comment: in that case, you can always use jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875607/filter-duplicate-options-from-select-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

although I believe there would be benefit in sharing the whole background information in order to brainstorm non DOM manipulation, here is a possible solution to remove duplicates

```
var usedNames = {};
$("select[name='company'] > option").each(function () {
    if(usedNames[this.text]) {
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
    }
});
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875607/filter-duplicate-options-from-select-dropdown)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was interested in a solution without using any external programs, other than SP and SPD 2010.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708014/remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-drop-down-list-using-javascript

Comment: I have zero knowledge of javascript. Where am I supposed to put the code..?

Comment: you have to embed your script withing a script tag. you can edit the page and add it or use a content editor webpart. you will have to try for yourself

Comment: All right. I think I might have found a workaround though, so I might as well try that first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to remove duplicate value temporary while its showing to user
take all the values of dropdown in an array and match the values if its present in an arrray if yes delete the particular array and again bind all the array to dropdown using jquery

Comment: and you managed to write all of that without a single comma :p